# Controling a TextView from a different thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an `Activity` class of a xml which uses another class caled "helper", in helper i took control of the the `TextView` by sending  the context of the `Activty` class.

The problem is that in helper i am using a thread to do something, and everytime it does it i want to change the text of the textView(it does it a couple of times in a loop).

the Stack Trace errors:

```
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-183
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15473)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6452)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3696)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at com.example.snake.GameView.AllChecks(GameView.java:175)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at com.example.snake.GameView.run(GameView.java:129)
03-12 18:30:55.533: E/AndroidRuntime(5317):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

EDIT: i excedenly put the wrong stack trace, i have edit it now . although i generaly got my answer that you cant control a textview from a nother thread

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot update a `TextView` from another thread. Your specific problem is a `NullPointerException`, though, triggered by `onCreate()` on your main application thread. Without your source code, though, nobody can help you determine where your bug is.

Comment: My mistake, i have excedently put the worng app stack trace, i have updated it. if still needed tell me and i will add the code

Comment: but i got my answer, i cant control a textview from another thread

Answer (score 2):

Each view has a [post method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) that will be called on the UI thread.

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("something");
    }
});
```

But your problem is somewhere else as far as you got NullPointerException

Comment: I excedently put the wrong stack trace, i have edited the main post

Comment: @Omer: You cannot update the `TextView` from another thread. Whether you use `post()` (as shown above), or `runOnUiThread()`, or an `AsyncTask` rather than an ordinary thread, or something else, is up to you. But you have to arrange for your UI to be updated on the main application thread.

Comment: do you have link explaining about that more? or maby can you give me ways how to do that. Thank you very much